# Upload de foto automaticamente com JQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário onde a foto aparece como preview ao ser selecionada para upload:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de que, ao selecionar a foto, fizesse o upload automaticamente. Como eu passaria os valores para a página **alterar-foto.php**?

O código segue abaixo:

```
<div class="faq-profile-btn">
   <label for="imagem" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Nova Foto</label>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" style="margin-top: -10px" onclick="excluirImagem()">Excluir Foto</button>
</div>
<input type="file" name="FotoPerfil" id="imagem" onchange="previewImagem()">
<div>    

    <script>
    function previewImagem(){

      var input = document.getElementById("imagem");
      var nome = input.files[0].name;
      var extensao = nome.split('.').pop();

      if(extensao != 'jpeg' && extensao != 'jpg' && extensao != 'png'){
         $('#acessar').modal('show');
      }else{
        var imagem = document.querySelector('input[name=FotoPerfil]').files[0];
        var preview = document.querySelector('img');
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('FotoPerfil', $('#imagem')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'alterar-foto-perfil.php',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        }
        if(imagem){
            reader.readAsDataURL(imagem);
        }else{
            preview.src = "";
        }
    }
  }
    function excluirImagem(){
         var preview = document.querySelector('img');
         preview.src = "img/foto_usuario.png";
    }
</script>
```

Ao usar o código acima, ele me retorna valor 0.

Comment: Olá Ricardo, fiz conforme o link indicado, mas não resolveu. Alterei meu post adaptando o trecho do código.

Comment: Utilize `data.append('FotoPerfil', $('#imagem')[0].prop('files')[0]);`

Comment: Olá Valdeir. Fiz dessa forma, mas quando faço isso, a imagem não aparece mais no preview e nem é feito o upload.